# GetModuleHandle implementation doesnt work

Tags: c, windows, winapi

For training purpose, i make my own implementation of the WINAPI function GetModuleHandle

here is it:

```c
PVOID SelfGetModuleHandle(PCWSTR name) {

    PEB* pPeb = RtlGetCurrentPeb();//getting Process Environement Bloc
    PPEB_LDR_DATA pLdr = pPeb->Ldr; //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/ns-winternl-peb
    LIST_ENTRY Lentry = pLdr->InMemoryOrderModuleList;//https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/ns-winternl-peb_ldr_data
    LIST_ENTRY FirstLentry = Lentry;
    do
    {
        LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY LDataTableEntry = *(LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY*)Lentry.Flink;
        if (StrCmpW(LDataTableEntry.FullDllName.Buffer, name) == 0) {
            printf("Base foud: %p\n", LDataTableEntry.DllBase);
            return (LDataTableEntry.DllBase);
        }
        Lentry = *Lentry.Flink;
    } while (memcmp(&Lentry, &FirstLentry, sizeof(LIST_ENTRY)));
    return NULL;
}
```

I thought my function was pretty cool and working, but the example code gets a segfault

```c
typedef
double
(__stdcall* POW)( //pow from NTDLL (offset 0x151498)
    double a,
    double b
    );

int main(){
    HMODULE dllBase = (HMODULE)SelfGetModuleHandle(L"ntdll.dll");//00000000001F8000 instead of 00007FFD36FD0000
    POW pow = (POW)GetProcAddress(dllBase, "pow");
    printf("%f", pow(2.0,3.0));

}
```

I'm searching what did I do wrong but can't find.

Maybe I'm not getting the right dllbase for this, in the wrong table, or maybe the PVOID need a bigger conversion for being a HMODULE, but i don't think this is that.

Thanks.

Comment: Re "*maybe the PVOID need a bigger conversion for being a HMODULE*", `HMODULE` is defined as `HINSTANCE`, which is defined as `PVOID`. So no. (`PVOID` is defined as `void *`.) [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types)

Comment: @ikegami yeah ik, i was talking about the difference between DllBase from LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY and the the expected value for GetProcAddress, not the type itself

Comment: SIGSEGV is not something you will encounter on Windows. Please explain the issue in a way that coincides with reality. Use a debugger to uncover helpful insights.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm doing this, my program tries to reach an address who doesn't exist in the current context

Comment: This cast is wrong: `LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY LDataTableEntry = *(LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY*)Lentry.Flink;` You need to adjust from the offset of the appropriate list entry to the head of the struct.

Comment: `Lentry = *Lentry.Flink;` and `memcmp(&Lentry, &FirstLentry, sizeof(LIST_ENTRY))` - this is something

Comment: @IInspectable: Assuming he actually got SIGSEGV, he wouldn't be the first programmer to develop Windows software on Wine first.

Comment: There are no *"segfaults"* on Windows either. If you observe an access violation there's nothing wrong with calling it an access violation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CONTAINING_RECORD` to adjust from the LIST_ENTRY pointer to the head of the struct. And a memcmp isn't necessary to terminate the loop.

Try something like this:

```
PLIST_ENTRY current = pPeb->Ldr->InMemoryOrderModuleList.Flink;
while ((current != NULL) && (current != &pPeb->Ldr->InMemoryOrderModuleList))
{
    LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY* module = (LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY*)CONTAINING_RECORD(current, LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY, InMemoryOrderLinks);
    wprintf(L"%p %p ", module, module->DllBase);
    wprintf(L"'%wZ' ", &module->FullDllName);
    wprintf(L"'%wZ' ", &module->BaseDllName);
    wprintf(L"\n");
    current = current->Flink;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is right; for reasons I don't understand. When I ran a loop like this against my own 64 bit process, I got the load address for kernel32.dll; but passing that to GetProcAddress didn't work.

Comment: @Joshua, For me, running this test code results in the expected output on x64 app + Win10 (foundkernel32 assigned during the loop on matching wcscmp):

    HMODULE kernel32 = GetModuleHandleA("kernel32");
    printf("%p\n", foundkernel32);
    printf("%p\n", kernel32);
    printf("%p\n", GetProcAddress(foundkernel32, "FindFirstFileW"));
    printf("%p\n", GetProcAddress(kernel32, "FindFirstFileW"));

Comment: Don't know what to tell you. I finally solved my problem by locating GetModuleHandle using the load address and calling it.

Comment: `(current != NULL)` not need, and cast `(LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY*)CONTAINING_RECORD` also not need. what is need (be good) use `LdrLockLoaderLock / LdrUnlockLoaderLock`

Comment: You rocks, so my problem comes from a lag at each iteration in LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY ? I thought that if i had a lag i cannot get the DllName, in my first code, but I can